# Invert python dictionary from {key : [x, y, z]} to {x: key, y : key, z : key}

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry, if this one is duplicate, but I am new to python and haven't found solution by googling.

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
{
   1 : ['x', 'y'],
   2 : ['z'],
   3 : ['a']
}
```

All values in lists are guaranteed to be unique.
And I want to transform this dictionary to:

```
{
   'x' : 1,
   'y' : 1,
   'z' : 2,
   'a' : 3
}
```

What is the most pythonic and clean way to write this?

Comment: That first dictionary is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: sorry, added commas

Comment: Remember that this can only work if all values across the lists are unique. Dictionaries require unique keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dct = {
   1 : ['x', 'y'],
   2 : ['z'],
   3 : ['a']
}

print({key:val for val, keys in dct.items() for key in keys})
```

Output:

```
{'a': 3, 'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
d = {
1 :['x', 'y'],
2 :['z'],
3 :['a']
}

'''
{
   'x' : 1,
   'y' : 1,
   'z' : 2,
   'a' : 3
}
'''

d2 = {}


for k,v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        d2[i] = k


print(d2)
```

**Output:**

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 2, 'a': 3}
[Finished in 0.2s]
```